# SQL remove autonamed constraints

Tags: sql, sql-server, constraints

I have created a few constraints on my table with a script without specifying the constraint name. As a result, I ended up having constraints like `FK__DOC_OBGS___kntr___54E63309` for example.

Is it possible to drop that constraints without specifying the exact constraint name ?

For example, something like this (which doesn't work)

```
ALTER TABLE DOC_OBGS_10 DROP CONSTRAINT LIKE 'FK__DOC_OBGS___kntr%'
```

The problem is that we have a lot of databases with this table and I need to remove all the constraints from the tables, but apparently the name is different for each table.

Comment: This is another good argument for why constraint should **always** be explicitly named according to a naming convention of your choice ...

Comment: Yes, people learn by their mistakes :))

Comment: Simple Solution => https://stackoverflow.com/a/49753774/185022

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
DECLARE @sql1 NVARCHAR(MAX);
SELECT @sql1 = c
FROM
(
    SELECT 'ALTER TABLE DOC_INVS_1 DROP CONSTRAINT ' + CONSTRAINT_NAME + '; '
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'DOC_INVS_1'
    and CONSTRAINT_NAME LIKE 'FK__DOC_INVS___kntr%' 
) T(c);

EXEC(@sql1);
```

Answer (score 6):

DDL commands in SQL do not cooperate with like operator.

However, you may use information_schema views and easily build SQL for drop constraint commands, like this:

```
SELECT 'ALTER TABLE DOC_OBGS_10 DROP CONSTRAINT ' + CONSTRAINT_NAME
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.REFERENTIAL_CONSTRAINTS 
WHERE CONSTRAINT_NAME LIKE 'FK__DOC_OBGS___kntr%'
```

Comment: Thanks. I used your idea and came with with this solution for my case:   : SELECT 'ALTER TABLE DOC_INVS_1 DROP CONSTRAINT ' + CONSTRAINT_NAME
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'DOC_INVS_1'
and CONSTRAINT_NAME LIKE 'FK__DOC_INVS___kntr%'  the problem is, how to exuce the query that is returned by the script? I tried using the Exec but I guess I have to include some brackets or something. Sorry, I'm newbie with SQL

Comment: Which DBMS do you use? MS-SQL?

Comment: Just copy & paste the result rows, which together form your DDL script, into query window. Run script with F5

Comment: I'm going to execute this script for all tables so I'm going to need something with the exec command

Comment: Please look at my another answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14413573/generate-script-for-triggers-only-using-script-wizard/14413819#14413819. You can use idea from there to accumulate "drop constraint" scripts into single table. Later just select scripts from that table and use copy paste.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I figured it out how to execute the command

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar issue after using the Access to SQL Server upsizing tool.  In my case I needed to loop all of the tables for matching constraints, which can be done like this:

```
DECLARE @sql1 NVARCHAR(MAX);

-- Concatenate all the drop statements in the inner loop into a single SQL string
SELECT @sql1 = STUFF((SELECT '; ' + a.t FROM 
(
    -- find all the constraints we're interested in and create a list of 
    -- SQL statements to drop them
    SELECT 'ALTER TABLE [' + p.name + '] DROP CONSTRAINT [' + o.name + ']' as t
    FROM sys.objects o
    left join sys.objects p on o.parent_object_id = p.object_id 
    WHERE o.name LIKE '%disallow_zero_length' 
) a
FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 2, '')

print @sql1

-- Execute the bit concatenated drop statement
EXEC(@sql1);
```

You can avoid the `STUFF` method in later versions of SQL Server, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/194852/how-to-concatenate-text-from-multiple-rows-into-a-single-text-string-in-sql-serv) for more on that.